# How do I make tweepy work with if/else statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, twitter, tweepy

So here is my code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyStreamListener())
myStream.filter(follow=['xxx'])

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

def on_status(self, status):
    path = "/images"
    random_file = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))])
    tweet = myStream.filter(follow=['xxx'])
    text = "test"
    if("@username" in tweet):
        pass
    else:
        print("answering @" + status.user.screen_name + " tweetID " + status.id_str + " with : " + text.rstrip())
        api.update_with_media(random_file, status="@" + status.user.screen_name + " " + text, in_reply_to_status_id=status.id)
    print(tweet)
```

Basically what I expect from this is that it will get all the live tweets from a certain user and then if that user's username is in the tweet, skip it, and if not then reply with a random image and text. When I run this it does absolutely nothing even when there is a new tweet. If I get rid of the if/else statements then it will start replying but it replies to its own reply. Also I am not sure if my update with media is the correct keyword to be using. Any help??

Comment: `"@username"` is literally `"@username"`. Did you want to use the user name instead?

Comment: I put placeholders for things like username and user id. Imagine that `@username` is replaced with the person that I want to be replying to. The whole idea is that when that user's tweet is retweeted it shows as `"RT @username blah blah"` and if they are commented on it looks like `"@username blah blah"`. This is basically just to stop it from replying to other peoples replies and retweets.

Comment: Does `myStream.filter(follow=['xxx'])` return a single tweet, or a _list_ of tweets?

Comment: It returns the latest tweet

Comment: What is the type of `tweet`?  Is it just a string, or is it some custom class object?

Comment: I belive it is a string

Comment: As @DYZ pointed out, `if("@username" in tweet):` is looking for the literal string `@username`.  If that is your real code, then that's the problem, otherwise please update the question to contain your real code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that is the issue. That's how it checks if the persons username is in the tweet. Isn't it just seeing if the username is in the tweet string and if so to just do a "pass" and if not to reply to them?

Comment: `if("@username" in tweet):` checks for the literal value `@username`, which presumably is not the user's actual name.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. Yeah when I am actually going to use the script I'll set the string for username to the person's username. Its only going to be replying to one person.

Answer (score 0):

`tweet` is a `Status` object (a sort of a `dict()`). The text of the tweet is in `tweet["full_text"]`. That's where you should search for the user name.

Comment: if I convert tweet to a str then it still prints the same text as before. The code still doesn't go to the else statement.

Comment: Perhaps the user name _is_ in the tweets?

Comment: I have the program print the tweet and the username isnt in it. Also when I set x=False and change the if statement to if(x==True) it still does nothing

Comment: It is hard to answer your questions without having your data. The proposed solution is correct to the extent that your explanation of te problem is correct.